# Only show HDRI lighting in the surface illuminated with sun light

Tags: lighting, hdri

I'm trying to make a series of moons in blender. I'm on cycles and have a very simple set up for the moment.

I have a UV sphere as my moon, a camera and a sun light that can rotate to simulate the phases of the moon.

The results look like this:

[image: Moon 1]

This is a very simple example. But I want to create a different material moons. Let's say one is rock, another one gold or glass.

In my experience the only way to make this materials look realistic is using and HDRI.

So I set up a HDRI with an environment texture, added some roughness and the mateial gold starts looking better:

[image: Moon 2]

But as you can see, the HDRI illuminates the whole sphere, so I loose control about the moon phase.

Is there any way I can only use the HDRI in the surface that the sun is illuminating, like the first moon from above?

I've been trying with light pad node with no luck at all... asked chat gpt, watched a ton of YT videos but I'm not able to figure it out. And it's key for me to have realistic golden moons for my collection.

PS: keep in mind that I'd love to keep it as procedural as possible, so I can create a ton of moons at scale!

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can edit the HDRI image, just paint dark the part that you want to keep dark

Comment: Ty! But will be able to animate it with that?

Comment: What kind of animation do you mean? Like rotating the HDRI? Another solution (Cycles) would be to put an object that would mask the HDRI and prevent the reflexion

Comment: I'd like to animate the moon phase change ;)

Comment: You could create a half sphere that you'd rotate and that would mask the reflexion of the HDRI? But maybe show a storyboard of the different images of moon that you plan to show

Comment: Gonna try it for sure, thank you